# Etymologie des Ortsnamens »Bezanika« aus dem Roman »Jakob der Lügner«

Tags: etymology, book

Ich hab vor einigen Wochen »Jakob der Lügner« gelesen (und war, von einem Schulbuch, positiv überrascht) und mir stellte sich eine Frage, die mir meine Lehrerin nicht beantworten konnte.

Weiß jemand, was die Etymologie des Namens der Stadt ist, vor der die Russen sind? »Bezanika«.

Ist das einfach ein Modewort ohne jede Bedeutung? Oder ist das sowas wie »Hoffnung« auf polnisch oder sowas? Ich finde dazu nichts, was mir irgendwie weiterhilft.

Comment: Kannst Du etwas mehr über diese Stadt sagen, vor allem, wo sie gelegen sein soll?

Comment: Das ist nicht so ganz klar. Man weiß nur, dass sie etwa 400-500km von dem Ort gelegen haben soll (Richtung Osten), wo der Roman spielt. Aber selbst der Ort ist nicht real bekannt und lokalisierbar. Es dürfte also etwas weiter östlich liegen als das heutige Polen oder am Rande des heutigen Polens.

Comment: Der Name sieht versucht östlich aus. Sollte Deutsch dabei sein, dann wohl als Akronym oä.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_der_L%C3%BCgner) sagt, der Name sei frei erfunden, und fügt nichts bei.

Comment: Google Translate sagt, für pl→en (pl→de ist nicht zu empfehlen): _beza→meringue_ (Baiser) oder _kiss_ (Kuss) und _nika→speaker_ (Sprecher). Daraus etwas zu schließen, würde aber gewagt sein.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literature or geography, respectively.

Comment: Literature is a part of the question, sure, but not geography. But it's a german book and where else should I ask this? The author was german and the language (if any) where that has any meaning is never disclosed. I believe, the german.se was the best choice.

Comment: Die Frage hat nichts mit Ethymologie zu tun, da der angefragte Eigenname (wie bei Wikipedia nachlesbar) ein Phantasiewort ist. Sie hätte auch Huxlipuxli heißen können... Warum der Schriftsteller sich dafür entschieden hat, kann dir kein deutsches Sprachforum erklären, und es gibt offenbar auch keine verfügbare Erklärung vom Autor selbst dazu. Deswegen ist die Frage zu schließen.

Comment: @falkb: Dass es keine Erklärung vom Autor gibt wäre aber eine entscheidende Information. Wenn es definitiv keine gibt kann man sich das Suchen und Spekulieren sparen, weiß das aber erst wenn diese Information verbreitet wird.

Comment: Im Kosovo liegt ein Berg/Dorf namens Beženik.